# Prove that if $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=L$ then $\lim_{x\to c} 7f(x)=7L$

Tags: limits

Prove that if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=L$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c} 7f(x)=7L$

I've never worked with limits, yet am trying to figure out how to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of the limit, given any $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{7}$ whenever $|x-c|<\delta$.

Then given $\epsilon >0$, $|7f(x)-7L| =7|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-c|<\delta$.